# How to use a .NET method that takes Type from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Simply, I want to use the `FileSecurity.GetAccessRules` API from PowerShell. The method signature looks like this in C#

```
public AuthorizationRuleCollection GetAccessRules(
    bool includeExplicit,
    bool includeInherited,
    Type targetType)
```

But I can't work out how to do a `typeof` from PS to specify the last argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `[System.Type]::GetType()` method, just enclose the type name in square brackets:

```
(Get-Acl D:\Path\To\Object).GetAccessRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[System.Type]::GetType("System.Security.Principal.NTAccount")
```

E.g.

```
PS L:\> $accessEnum = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::Access    
PS L:\> $fs = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity -ArgumentList "L:\Logs", $accessEnum    
PS L:\> $rules = $fs.GetAccessRules($true, $false, [System.Type]::GetType("System.Security.Principal.NTAccount"))
```